# Drawing the shape of the detected object?

Tags: java, opencv, drawing, computer-vision

I successfully detected the upperbody of the person in a picture. But all I can do now is draw a rectangle around the upperbody. How can I trace the upperbody?, i.e. draw a line (that looks like the upperbody) around the detected upperbody. I'm working with OpenCV.
Here's some code from the detection system.

```
  if(new File("E:\\OpenCV\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml\\").isFile())
        { System.out.println("file there"); }
        cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier("E:\\OpenCV\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml");
        inputPic = Highgui.imread(picSrcDir + picName);
        MatOfInt intw = new MatOfInt(1);
        MatOfDouble dble = new MatOfDouble(1.05);
        rect = new MatOfRect();
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(inputPic, rect, intw, dble);
        Scalar color = new Scalar(0, 0, 255);
        System.out.println("Number Of Hits: " + rect.toArray().length);
        Rect[] rectArr = rect.toArray();
        System.out.println(rectArr.length);
        int i=0;
        for(Rect recta : rectArr){
            System.out.println(rectArr[i]); i++;
            Core.rectangle(inputPic, new Point(recta.x, recta.y), new Point(recta.x+recta.width, recta.y+recta.height), color);
        }
        Highgui.imwrite(picName, inputPic);
```

Comment: You need to look into edge and feature detection, you are halfway there having figured out the bounds of the upper body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After detecting the people upperbody rect:

1. Remove the rect background, keeping just the person upperbody.
2. Binarize the image.
3. Apply morphological boundary algorithm to trace the upperbody.

**Example:**

[image]

OpenCV provides these algorithms. However, the example above was developed using [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/). The source code is presented below:

```
public class TraceShape {

    public TraceShape(){
        // Load Plug-in
        MarvinImagePlugin boundary = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.morphological.boundary");

        // Load image
        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/person.jpg");

        // Binarize
        MarvinImage binImage = MarvinColorModelConverter.rgbToBinary(image, 245);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(binImage, "./res/person_bin.png");

        // Boundary
        boundary.process(binImage.clone(), binImage);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(binImage, "./res/person_boundary.png");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TraceShape();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although my specs have changed I can still use the binarization method, so cheers.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel I get an empty image when saving `person_boundary.png`

Comment: @juanmf I had the problem likes your before I realized and changed `boundary.process(binImage, binImage);` to `boundary.process(binImage.clone(), binImage);`